# order_by('-distance') not working as expected

Tags: django, geolocation, geospatial, geodjango, geos

I am trying to make a database query that gives me 20 closest users ordered by the distance (so closest first) I am doing the follwoing

```
distance_mi = 100

origin = GEOSGeometry('SRID=4326;'+ 'POINT('+ str(user_profile.current_location.x)+' '+str(user_profile.current_location.y)+')')

close_users = UserProfile.objects.exclude(user = user).filter(current_location__distance_lte=(origin, D(mi=distance_mi))).distance(origin).order_by('-distance')[:20]
```

but this returns back 3 users (which is correct) but the first user is 0 mi away, the second is 8 mi away and the third is 0 mi away where as I am excepting the 8 mi user to be at the very end.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong in this.

Also, the `UserProfile` has the following Model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This field is required.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # Other fields here
    current_location = models.PointField(null = True)
    seller_current_location = models.PointField(null = True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.user.get_full_name())
```

Comment: Does `UserProfile` contain geographic fields other than `current_location`? If so, `distance()` may be using a different field than you expect. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#geoqueryset-methods) on the `field_name` argument to `distance()`.

Comment: Also, if you want "closest first" you should be ordering on `'distance'`. (Though that wouldn't explain the unordered results you're reporting.)

Comment: @KevinHenry yes it has two PointFields pleace look at the update, should I specify the field_names for both?

Comment: @KevinHenry yes I just added `distance(origin, field_name='current_location')` and that fixed it. and yes I changed `order_by('-distance')` to `order_by('distance')` Thank you so much!! please put this down as the solution so that I can accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `UserProfile` contains more than one geographic field, you should specify the one you want with the `field_name` argument to `distance()`.

```
UserProfile.objects.exclude(user=user).filter(current_location__distance_lte=(origin, D(mi=distance_mi))).distance(origin, field_name='current_location').order_by('distance')[:20]
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#geoqueryset-methods) for more details.